# Converting cubic cm to litres in python

Tags: python

I want to write a function that when I input the dimensions of a truncated cone (a cup) and an amount of liquid in litres returns how many of these cups can be filled up with the amount of liquid.

```
def number_of_cups(bottom_radius, top_radius, height, litres_of_liquid):

    volume = math.pi / 3 * height * (bottom_radius**2 + top_radius * bottom_radius +  top_radius**2)

    return int(filled_cup)
```

This is as far as I have got, I don't understand how I convert the volume in cm^3 to litres using Python. How would I incorporate the conversion of 1L = 1000 into the code

I am running Python 3 to clear up any version confusion.

Any help is much obliged.

Comment: That's easy: `1l = 1000 cm^3`. :)

Comment: Thank you, I am however familiar with the conversion but I just can't seem to figure out how to incorporate it into my code.

Comment: Judging from your question, you seem to know how to multiply and divide. What's more to know?

Comment: I know it seems simple but I just can't seem to wrap my head around it, would I add in filled_cup = volume / 1000 and then when I add in the parameters it should all work?

Answer (score 2):

[There are 1000 cubic centimeters in a liter](http://www.futureboy.us/fsp/frink.fsp?fromVal=liter&toVal=centimeter%5E3), so divide by 1000.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the conversion factors between units, you can look them up online. I Googled "converting volume to capacity", and came up with [this handy tool](http://www.convert-me.com/en/convert/volume/), which tells me that 1 cubic centimeter is 0.001 litres. So, multiple your cc result by that number (or, equivalently, but possibly more accurately in the face of binary floating point numbers, divide by 1000) and you have your answer.

Comment: Hey, so if I was to add something like this in 
filled_cup = 1000/volume
That should give me the right answer?
Thanks

Comment: @MrWallace litres are bigger, so you'll have less of them - meaning you want `volume/1000`.